# First order differential equation with initial condition

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I need to solve the following differential equation with initial condition $y(0)=1$
$$x^2(2y+y^2)dx=2x^3dy$$
Solving the equation I end up with following
$$y=\frac{2Cx}{1-Cx}$$
But in order to solve it I assumed x<>0 which contradicts the initial condition (using the initial condition with the above solution I end up 1=0).

Is there any way to solve the above differential equation taking into account the initial condition?

Comment: Can you show your work? It is unclear what is it that you mean by "I assumed x<>0 which contradicts the initial condition." In fact, the way you wrote the equation makes it unclear whether the initial condition is even consistent with the differential equation itself. You should rewrite the differential equation as $$2y+y^2=2xy'$$ and work from there.

Comment: @Angel  In order to do as you suggest, he has to assume $x\neq 0.$

Comment: @B.Goddard In that case, that just means the differential equation is incompatible with the given initial condition. In fact, as I demonstrated in my answer, there is no function that is differentiable at $0$ that satisfies the equation everywhere in $\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$ that also satisfies the initial condition.

Answer (score -1):

You should rewrite the equation as $y(x)^2+2y(x)=2xy'(x).$ Notice that $y^2+2y=y(y+2),$ so what you have is $y(x)=-2$ and $y(x)=0$ as special solutions, though these do not satisfy your initial condition. To obtain the other solutions, you have that $$1=\frac{2xy'(x)}{y(x)[y(x)+2]}=\frac{([y(x)+2]-y(x))xy'(x)}{y(x)[y(x)+2]}=\frac{xy'(x)}{y(x)}-\frac{xy'(x)}{y(x)+2}.$$ The problem here is that this clearly demonstrates this differential equation is incompatible with the condition $y(0)=1.$ This is because it implies $$1=\frac{2\cdot0\cdot{y'(0)}}{y(0)[y(0)+2]}=\frac{0\cdot{y'(0)}}3=0y'(0),$$ which is impossible. What this suggests is that $y$ is not differentiable at $0,$ but satisfies the differential equation everywhere in $\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}.$ In that case, though, the initial condition given is irrelevant, as it does not constrain the set of solutions at all.

The equation can be written as $$\frac{y'(x)}{y(x)}-\frac{y'(x)}{y(x)+2}=\frac1{x}.$$ There are three families of solutions to consider here.  One family of solutions is when $y(x)\lt-2,$ in which case, the differential equation implies $$\ln[-y(x)]-\ln[-y(x)-2]=\ln(-x)+A,\,x\lt0$$ $$\ln[-y(x)]-\ln[-y(x)-2]=\ln(x)+B,\,x\gt0$$ which is equivalent to $$\frac{y(x)}{y(x)+2}=-e^Ax,\,x\lt0$$ $$\frac{y(x)}{y(x)+2}=e^Bx,\,x\gt0$$ which is equivalent to $$y(x)=\frac{-2x}{e^{-A}+x},\,x\lt0$$ $$y(x)=\frac{2x}{e^{-B}-x},\,x\gt0.$$

Another family of solutions to consider is when $-2\lt{y(x)}\lt0,$ in which case the differential equation implies $$\ln[-y(x)]-\ln[y(x)+2]=\ln(-x)+A,\,x\lt0$$ $$\ln[-y(x)]-\ln[y(x)+2]=\ln(x)+B,\,x\gt0$$ which is equivalent to $$\frac{y(x)}{y(x)+2}=e^Ax,\,x\lt0$$ $$\frac{y(x)}{y(x)+2}=-e^Bx,\,x\gt0$$ which is equivalent to $$y(x)=\frac{2x}{e^{-A}-x},\,x\lt0$$ $$y(x)=\frac{-2x}{e^{-B}+x},\,x\gt0$$

The first family of solutions is the same family of solutions as when $y(x)\gt0,$ and also, that family only works on the region $(-e^{-A},e^{-B})\setminus\{0\}.$ Outside that region, one can have the second family, or one of the constant solutions. However, there is no family of solutions where $y(0)=1$ is allowed.

Comment: Your differential equation is incompatible with the initial condition.  The original differential equation is not.

Comment: @Paul There is no function $y:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ that is differentiable at $0$ that satisfies the original differential equation everywhere that also satisfies the initial condition, because in order to satisfy the original differential equation everywhere, it must satisfy my differential equation in $\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\},$ but any function that satisfies my differential equation in $\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$ either is not differentiable at $0,$ or does not satisfy the initial condition. That is entirely the point that my answer proves. You would know this if you understood.

Comment: @Paul If you think I am wrong, then enlighten me: what function satisfies the original differential equation everywhere *and* the initial condition? Where did my solution go wrong, then?

Comment: The solution went wrong when you divided out the $x^2$ to get your DE.  You can't do that with a $x=0$ initial condition.  The DE is singular at $x=0$, so the solution is likely unusual.

Comment: @Paul *You can't do that with a x=0 initial condition.* Yes, you can, and my answer proves that. You have not shown how my answer is wrong, you are merely repeating a statement already addressed by the answer. If you want, here is an explicit version that does not involve dividing by $x^2:$ $x^2[y(x)^2+2y(x)]=2x^3y'(x)$ implies $x^2[2xy'(x)-y(x)^2-2y(x)]=0.$ At $x=0,$ this equation is true for every differentiable $y:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R},$ so for some such $y$ to satisfy the equation elsewhere, it must satisfy $2xy'(x)-y(x)^2-2y(x)=0.$ You have not disproven this.

Comment: @Paul *The DE is singular at x=0, so the solution is likely unusual.* Then go ahead and provide such a solution, or prove its existence. If you cannot do it, then you are wrong. It is as simple as that. You have not properly addressed my answer, so if you cannot provide any counterexamples, then your criticism is wrong and meaningless.

Comment: @Paul Also, for what it is worth, it is well-known in the theory of differential equations, both ordinary and partial, that an equation $f(t)y'(t)=F[t,y(t)]$ is not guaranteed to have solutions that are regular at $t$ such that $f(t)=0,$ and if it does, those solutions are typically singularities of $F,$ except for when certain very strict conditions are met.

Comment: "$x2[y(x)2+2y(x)]=2x3y′(x)$ implies $x2[2xy′(x)−y(x)2−2y(x)]=0$."  Yes, of course.

"At $x=0$, this equation is true for every differentiable $y:R→R,$ so for some such y to satisfy the equation elsewhere, it must satisfy $2xy′(x)−y(x)2−2y(x)=0$" is absolute nonsense.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132912/discussion-between-angel-and-paul).